# I created a git repository on the openwrt router, but I got the error on my mac

Tags: git, openwrt, opkg

opkg.conf:

```
src/gz chaos_calmer_base http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/bcm53xx/generic/packages/base/
src/gz chaos_calmer_packages http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/bcm53xx/generic/packages/packages/
dest root /data
dest ram /tmp
lists_dir ext /data/var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /data
arch all 1
arch noarch 1
arch bcm53xx 10*
```

I installed git, run git got the error：

```
git: symbol '__ctype_b': can't resolve symbol
```

Add path in /etc/profile solved this error:

```
Export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/data/lib:/data/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib'
```

I got a new error when git clone on my mac：

```
git-upload-pack: symbol '__ctype_b': can't resolve symbol
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Looks like an error when running git on the router，please help me.

Comment: My understanding of the problem is the following: when git on the mac connects to the router sshd on the server doesn't run `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile` so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set. You have to find a way to run git at openwrt without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Possibly you could just configure your library paths in `/etc/ld.so.conf` so that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is unnecessary. If you're installing `git` from source, you can also embed an `RPATH` into the binary so that it knows where to look for the libraries.

Comment: @phd You understand right，what should I do?

Comment: @larsks My ability is limited, I will try to cross-compile `git`. can you say in detail? I can't find `ld.so.conf` in etc